# Ramanujan Summation not consistent with Riemann's Zeta function?

Tags: riemann-zeta, divergent-series, ramanujan-summation

Wikipedia states that Ramanujan sums and the Riemann Zeta function [have the same values for even $k$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation#Sum_of_divergent_series):

$$1 + 2^{2k} + 3^{2k} + \cdots = 0\ (\Re)$$

However, I don't understand how this can be true, because when $k = 0$, because that gives us:

$$1 + 1 + 1 + \cdots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{0} = 0\ (\Re)$$

and yet we have $\zeta(0) = -1/2$, which are clearly unequal.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't the Ramanujan sum for $1 + 1 + 1 + \cdots$ also $-1/2$? I'm not sure how you're getting the $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty = 0$ though.

Comment: @HenrySwanson: If you plug in $k = 0$ in the first formula then you get $1 + 1 + 1 + \cdots = 0$, right?

Comment: I was told that identity was only for positive $k$. I don't know the proof though, so I can't verify that.

Comment: @HenrySwanson: Ohh I see... that would explain it. If someone finds a reference it would be a great answer.

Comment: Yes, the Wiki doesn't tell us what it means. It certainly doesn't mean negative even values, but it doesn't explicitly say so. It could be excluding zero as well.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64898/values-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-and-the-ramanujan-summation-how-strong-is.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Ramanujan summation doesn't always give an unique result, let's see: Ramanujan summation $\Re$ of the terms of a function f(x) is defined as:

$C(a)=\int_n^af(t)dt-\frac 1 2f(n)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty {B_{2k}\over (2k)!}f^{2k-1}(n)$

Where $B_i$ are the Bernoulli numbers.

Iff it has no divergence for $x=n$ then $\Re=C(0)$ but setting $a=0$ sometimes lead to different answers, instead of that try to put $a=1$ without forgetting that Riemann Zeta Function diverges both on $x=1$ and $x=0$ (Wikipedia treats only the two cases where a function doesn't do this). So $\Re=C(1)$ which is the only solution to the differential equation: $R(x)-R(x+1)=f(x)$ satisfying the relation: $\int_1^2R(t)dt=0$

Another way to show that is with the well-known identity: $\zeta(-k)=-\frac {B_{k+1}} {k+1}$ for every positive integer $k$ if you take $k=0$ you'll get $-\frac 1 2$ and if you take an even number $k=2n$ you'll get $0$ because every Bernoulli number with odd index is $0$.